# Is it okay to call exception-triggered debugging "post-mortem debugging"?

Tags: python, terminology, debugging

I heard the term "post-mortem debugging", and Wikipedia says it's debugging done after the program has crashed.

I often debug Python apps using a debugger that stops execution once an important-enough exception has been raised. Then I can use the debug probe to investigate.

Does this count as "post-mortem debugging"? Because the program doesn't really crash.

**EDIT:** If the answer is no, then what name would you use for the kind of debugging that I described?

Comment: Probably the term is "interactive debugging".

Comment: Well, that doesn't differentiate it much from any other kind of interactive debugging that does't get triggered by exceptions.

Comment: I suppose you could call it "dynamic breakpointing", but the technique's been around for a long time and hasn't had a special name before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  Post-mortem debugging involves using a debugger and a core file or other memory image.  If the program's still running, then it hasn't "died", so it's still pre-mortem.

EDIT: I don't think this technique has a specific name, "breakpointing on exceptions" is the term I'd use, although @Jeremy's suggestion is just as good.

Comment: Yes, and the term wouldn't typically be used to refer to an app running under a debugger on a development machine.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: OP's stated `"using a debugger that stops execution`", I'm not sure the specifics of Python, so it may kill the process, rather than pause execution.

Comment: It doesn't kill the process.